# With/Without Javascript form submission using ajax or normal form action

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am currently submitting a form using form action to a php script and i was going to implement ajax form submission also.

But a thought came to my mind that wouldn't it be nice to know if the client's browser has javascript enabled or disabled and submit the form accordingly as i don't want the no-javascript users to view a page that says "Enable Javascript or something"! as i have used both client and server side validations.

So, how should i know that a client has javascript and let him submit form by ajax and vice versa?

I found many QA's related to redirecting users to a page that says "Javascript disabled" and they mostly talked about  tags.

I would appreciate hearing you guys and your suggestions. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a form with a `submit` button.

In your javascript script put an handler on it, and call the `preventDefault` function to let your ajax code do the job.

So if javascript is enabled it will submit with ajax. If not it will submit it the default way .

EDIT:

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/CTwx2/

Basically the default behavior of a submit button is to send the data to the address indicated in the form tag.

With the handler defined in javascript & jquery, you stop this behavior and send the data by yourself through an ajax request (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Will you enlighten me little more?
Like @isJustMe said, i don't want to have 2 versions of same thing!
But this method sounds good. But what will be the function of preventDefault?

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. It's not that difficult than what i thought :D
I hope it works for me later!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have 2 versions of your site and redirect accordingly  using :

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">
</noscript>
```

**OR**

Wrap your form in your  `<noscript>` tags, and if javascript is enabled disable that form-